# Sorting a select element with multiple options selected reverses the order

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, select

I have a select element with a long list of people. I want to be able to select multiple people in the list and sort them up or down by clicking arrows. I thought I got it working but every time I move a selection up, the selected options reverse in order.

It's like the 2nd selected option moves up and also moves past the first...not sure what's going on. Thanks in advance!

```
var select = _select;
var optionsNodeList = select.options;
var options = [];
var selectedIndexes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < optionsNodeList.length; i++) {
    var option = optionsNodeList.item(i);
    options.push(option);
    if (option.selected) {
        selectedIndexes.push(i);
    }
}

var len = selectedIndexes.length;
var firstSelected = selectedIndexes[0];
var lastSelected = selectedIndexes[len-1];
if (isSortUp === true && firstSelected !== 0) {
    for (var i = 0, currIndex; i < len; i++) {
        var currIndex = selectedIndexes[i];
        insertBefore(options[currIndex], options[currIndex-1]);             
    }
} else if (isSortUp === false && lastSelected !== options.length-1) {
    for (var i = len-1, currIndex; i > -1; i--) {
        var currIndex = selectedIndexes[i];
        insertAfter(options[currIndex], options[currIndex+1]);
    }
}

function insertBefore(newNode, refNode) {
    refNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, refNode);
}
function insertAfter(newNode, refNode) {
    refNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, refNode.nextSibling);
}
```

Before pressing the up arrow:
[before screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8WeY.png)
After pressing the up arrow:
[after screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDE2Z.png)

Comment: Why loop at all?  Seems easier to just move the one element before or after to the front or back of the selected group.  Then it's just one moved element instead of moving the whole selected list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to loop at all.  Rather than move the entire group, just move the option before (or after):

```
if (isSortUp === true && firstSelected !== 0) {
    insertAfter(options[firstSelected - 1], options[lastSelected]);
} else if (isSortUp === false && lastSelected !== options.length-1) {
    insertBefore(options[lastSelected + 1], options[firstSelected]);
}
```

But, for completeness, the reason your order is being swapped is that you are re-ordering the elements in the DOM within your loop, but you do not re-order the array `options` that you have.  This extra array you use to store the options is not necessary.  If you change your code to use `select.options` directly, your code will actually work as you've written it without re-ordering your selected options on each click.

```js
document.getElementById("up").addEventListener("click", function(){
    move(true);
});
document.getElementById("down").addEventListener("click", function(){
    move(false);
});

function move(isSortUp){
    var select = document.getElementById("sel");
    var optionsNodeList = select.options;
    var options = [];
    var selectedIndexes = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < optionsNodeList.length; i++) {
        var option = optionsNodeList.item(i);
        options.push(option);
        if (option.selected) {
            selectedIndexes.push(i);
        }
    }

    var len = selectedIndexes.length;
    var firstSelected = selectedIndexes[0];
    var lastSelected = selectedIndexes[len-1];
    
    if (isSortUp === true && firstSelected !== 0) {
        insertAfter(options[firstSelected - 1], options[lastSelected]);
    } else if (isSortUp === false && lastSelected !== options.length-1) {
        insertBefore(options[lastSelected + 1], options[firstSelected]);
    }
}

function insertBefore(newNode, refNode) {
    refNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, refNode);
}
function insertAfter(newNode, refNode) {
    refNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, refNode.nextSibling);
}
```

```html
<select id="sel" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100px; height: 150px;">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
    <option>d</option>
    <option>e</option>
    <option>f</option>
    <option>g</option>
    <option>h</option>
    <option>i</option>
    <option>j</option>
</select>
<button id="up">up</button>
<button id="down">down</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9v32xs0o/

Comment: Thanks! It seems so obvious to move the non-selected element now that you say it. Naturally, I noticed way faster response when moving a hundred or so selected items. Also thanks for pointing out my mistake with options array. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You error is that you are placing the options before their previous one, so the second option "insertBefore" the first one.

Example:
Option1     - Index 0 
Option2 (Selected) - Index 1
Option3 (Selected) - Index 2

The first selected inserts before the Index 0 thats ok, the secod selectes inserts before the Index 1, so it on the top of index 1, not good.

you can do something like this to fix your problem.

```
if (isSortUp === true && firstSelected !== 0) {
    for (var i = 0, currIndex; i < len; i++) {
        var currIndex = selectedIndexes[i];
        if(i == 0){
          insertBefore(options[currIndex], options[currIndex-1]);             
        }else{
          insertAfter(options[currIndex], options[currIndex-1]); 
        }
    }
}
```

With that the first selected inserts before their previous one, what the rest of the selected are placing behind the first selected.

Comment: You shouldn't have "var" in your `if`.

Comment: Right, the var shouldn't be there, a typo mistake